# Links from external XML not working anymore, AS3/Flash

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Hope somebody can help me...I have an external XML file loading in Flash. It worked perfect but since this week not anymore. The links in the XML file are the problem.  I have no idea why.
In Flash I get the message:
`Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.`
The XML is loading the first time I click on the button and the  link works, but after that no text and links are loading at all!

I give the code that I use:

```
var txtFld:TextField = new TextField();
var txtFmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

var xml:XML;
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("background.xml");
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false,0,true);
function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
evt.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
xml = new XML(evt.target.data);
}

txtFmt.font = avenirRoman.fontName; 
txtFmt.size = 12; 
txtFmt.leading = 4;
txtFmt.color = 0x616161; 
txtFld.defaultTextFormat = txtFmt; 
txtFld.embedFonts = true;
txtFld.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
txtFld.thickness = -100;
txtFld.sharpness = 50;
txtFld.multiline = true;
txtFld.wordWrap = true; 
txtFld.width = 500; 
txtFld.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT; 
txtFld.x = 270; 
txtFld.y = 145;


btn10.addEventListener("click", afterClick2);
function afterClick2(e:Event):void {
txtFld.htmlText = xml.INFO[0].toString();
addChild(txtFld);

}

btn11.addEventListener("click", afterClick3);
function afterClick3(e:Event):void {
txtFld.htmlText = xml.INFO[1].toString();
addChild(txtFld);

}

btn12.addEventListener("click", afterClick4);
function afterClick4(e:Event):void {
txtFld.htmlText = xml.INFO[2].toString();
addChild(txtFld);

}
```

Then I tried to put in extra (IOErrorEvent) code:

```
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, catchIOError);
function catchIOError(event:IOErrorEvent){
trace("Error caught: "+event.type);
}
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("Invalid XML URL"));
trace("Continuing with script...");***
```

Then I get the message:
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at main3_fla::MainTimeline/afterClick2()

And the XML file is not loading at all.If I take out all the links in the XML, text is loading perfect.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe your XML are malformed. Can you show it?

Comment: Here's my XML:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GALLERY>


<INFO TITLE><![CDATA[<u><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">www.yahoo.com</a></u>


]]>
</INFO>

</GALLERY>

Comment: You're really opening a tag *<INFO TITLE>* and closing as *</INFO>* ?
If yes, that's the error.

Comment: sorry, I gave the wrong xml. Here's the good one I use:

Comment: <GALLERY>


<INFO><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">www.yahoo.com</a>]]></INFO>

</GALLERY>

Comment: <GALLERY>
<INFO><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">www.yahoo.com</a>]]></INFO>
</GALLERY>

Comment: I don't know what happens, but this editor doesn't give http before yahoo. But I'm sure the code is right...because it is working, only after clicking the link, the xml is not displayed in my Flash site anymore

Comment: I can't figure out anything that happened to your site. Try placing traces everywhere for debuging, maybe you can find the error.

Comment: I solved the problem, maybe it will help somebody else too:
I wrote this line extra:txtFld.setTextFormat(txtFmt);

and that helped. Among other things, for example a link in xml works good with this code:
<A XML-LINK="LINK" HREF="url" target="_blank">text</A>

and not <a href>

maybe it will help somebody else and thanks for your reply, it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

This entire "issue" is really weird, are you sure you are writing AS3-code? 
I can't for my life understand the following things:

1. What is your issue? Can you load your xml-file and all links
   once? Is the trouble the second time when you try to reload your xml
   file? Does it always work whenever you don't have links inside
   xml-file?
2. You mention a button that loads your xml file, I see no
   button in your code that provides that functionality
3. From where are you trying to load your xml-file, is it a local file from your
   computer or is it from the web somewhere (on a web-server)?
4. You do a new URLRequest("background.xml") but you provide no absolute
   URL, meaning this could be some kind of path change so
   "background.xml" links to something else the second time (no idea how, but anything is possible)
5. Your code seems weird I can't tell if the entire code is some part of a
   constructor or something else. You do "addChild" more than once,
   this could become an issue if txtFld is some kind of class member
   and there are multiple instances of the class.
6. I don't understand that IOErrorEvent-example you provided, you deliberatley throw an
   error, catch it somewhere and then expect it to continue with script
   outside of the catch block before the invalid urlRequest?

The Error #1009 thing you were describing is quite simple, when you
    enter that function, you don't have access to either variables
    "txtFld", "xml" or xml doesn't look as you expect it to.

This all boils down to the following:

- I can't help you with your issue unless you provider more context for
  when things are initialized/created and when things are called, as it
  is now you are mixing initialization and invocation without giving
  the correct context for either